# List of all posts in one custom post type in the edit screen of another

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

Please forgive me if this doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Is there a way to list all the posts created under one custom post type (eg: Blueprints) in the edit screen of another (eg: Buildings) in a checklist (or similar) so that individual bluebrints can be associated with individual buildings?

I hope that made sense.

Comment: Listing posts with checkboxes isn't going to automatically create a relation though is it, how do you plan to relate those posts to one another?

Comment: The checkboxes would act like custom meta boxes. So if Blueprint A and Blueprint B were selected in Building 1 they would appear as a custom field value

Comment: "**were selected in building 1**"? ... If it's the post listing, how are you in a given building? You're viewing a list, not a given single item.. (please try and expand on what is your describing or envisioning).. also please add that additional info to the question to avoid bloating the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are trying to make ralationship links between post types, the easiest way is to use the great "posts 2 posts" plugin by Scribu :
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/

here is the documentation :
https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki

hope that could help.

seb.

EDIT :

> Is there a way to list all the posts created under one custom post
>   type (eg: Blueprints) in the edit screen of another (eg: Buildings) in
>   a checklist (or similar)

yes ! in the edit screen of each post types depending on the associations you create between them. not a checklist, but similar, well, better ! this plugin gives you the ability to add/remove/reorder, with drag and drop, your linked posts/post types/pages and even users if you need...

> so that individual bluebrints can be associated with individual
>   buildings?

absolutely ! not only "one to one" relationships inbetween different post types, but also "many to many" and "one to many"... you choose. see the manual.